# Can't pickle <function stringToNgrams at 0x104144f28>: it's not the same object as __main__.stringToNgrams

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to run a function over a list of objects. However, this particular function does **not** belong to a class or module - it is defined directly above the multiprocessing code.

Here is my code:

```
def stringToNgrams(string,n):
    ngrams = set()
    sentenceArray = string.split(" ")
    for i in range(0,len(sentenceArray) - (n - 1)):
        ngramWords = sentenceArray[i:i + n]
        print(ngramWords)
        ngram = " ".join(ngramWords)
        print(ngram)
        ngrams.add(ngram)

from multiprocessing import Pool
ngramPool = Pool(3)
import functools
stringToNgrams = functools.partial(stringToNgrams,n=2) # So we can load n into stringToNgrams.
results = ngramPool.map(stringToNgrams,strings)
```

Here is my error message:

```
  File "/Users/montana/Documents/Capstone project/BBEditRunTemp-n_gram.py", line 76, in <module>
    results = ngramPool.map(stringToNgrams,strings)
  File "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/Users/montana/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function stringToNgrams at 0x104144f28>: it's not the same object as __main__.stringToNgrams
```

I can't seem to figure out what to do - if I use **main**.stringToNgrams, Python then complains that the name "**main**" is not defined. Please help me, and thank you!

Comment: I believe that if you put the `n=2` as a default in the function's parameter list, rather than adding it later via `functools.partial()`, this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue related to the functools.partial constructor. From [the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue1398):

> the liberal functools.partial
>   constructor makes it hard to pickle partial instances correctly.

Therefore, the answer is to do one of two things:

1) Make n an optional parameter

2) Create another function that passes 2 to the original function.